# Query working in SQL Server but not working in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

A company has a record of it's customers and their orders. I am writing a query to get the names of those customer(s) and order(s), who have the maximum price order within the first ten years of the first order. This select query is working in SQL Server but I am getting an error in MySQL

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '1 C.NAME, O.PRICE, O.ORDER_DATE FROM ORDERS O, CUSTOMERS C WHERE
>   O.PRICE = (SEL' at line 1

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(ID varchar(10), NAME varchar(50), ORDER_ID varchar(20));
  INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES('1','Tom','abcd');
  INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES('52','Lucy','fghi');
  INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES('43','Frank','klmn');
  INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES('64','Jane','opqr');
  INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES('565','Robert','xyz');

CREATE TABLE ORDERS(ID varchar(20), PRICE int, ORDER_DATE date);
  INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('abcd', 100, '1987-10-02');
  INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('fghi', 200, '1987-10-06');
  INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('klmn', 20, '1998-10-22');
  INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('opqr', 50, '1988-10-14');
  INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('xyz', 300, '1999-10-02');
  INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('fghi', 250, '1995-10-06');
  INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('klmn', 40, '1993-11-22');
  INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('abcd', 70, '1989-12-14');
  INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('klmn', 590, '1999-01-22');
  INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('opqr', 540, '1988-10-14');
  INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('fghi', 540, '1986-10-14');
  INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('abcd', 470, '1979-02-14');
```

---

```
SELECT C.NAME, O.PRICE
FROM ORDERS O, CUSTOMERS C 
WHERE O.PRICE = 
(
    SELECT MAX(PRICE) FROM ORDERS 
    WHERE ORDER_DATE BETWEEN 
    (SELECT TOP 1 ORDER_DATE FROM ORDERS ORDER BY ORDER_DATE) 
    AND 
    (SELECT TOP 1 DATEADD(year, 10, ORDER_DATE) FROM ORDERS ORDER BY ORDER_DATE)
) 
AND C.ORDER_ID = O.ID ORDER BY O.ORDER_DATE;
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `TOP`

Comment: Use LIMIT instead of TOP

Comment: (SELECT ORDER_DATE FROM ORDERS ORDER BY ORDER_DATE LIMIT 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this below option-

```
SELECT C.NAME, O.PRICE
FROM ORDERS O
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS C ON C.ORDER_ID = O.ID
/*Comma separated joins are old fashion now.
You should use Standard joining as shown*/
WHERE O.PRICE = 
(
    SELECT MAX(PRICE) 
    FROM ORDERS 
    WHERE ORDER_DATE BETWEEN 
    (SELECT MIN(ORDER_DATE) FROM ORDERS) 
    AND 
    (SELECT DATE_ADD(MIN(ORDER_DATE), INTERVAL 10 year) FROM ORDERS)
    /*In selecting date range, you will gain some performance here
    As this will select only the minimum date where as you are 
    selecting all dates first and keeping one row from them

    Also you are applying DATE_ADD on all rows of your table
    to generate the Upper date range which is also performance issue*/
) 
ORDER BY O.ORDER_DATE;
```

Comment: Thanks @mkRabbani, I accepted your answer as it has taken 2ms whereas my answer is taking 11ms so definitely your solution is better than me.

Comment: You are most welcome. Nice to hear that it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Nick, @Shivani for the quick support. corrected my query and it is working.

```
SELECT C.NAME, O.PRICE, O.ORDER_DATE
FROM ORDERS O, CUSTOMERS C 
WHERE O.PRICE = (
    SELECT MAX(PRICE) 
    FROM ORDERS 
    WHERE ORDER_DATE BETWEEN 
        (SELECT ORDER_DATE FROM ORDERS ORDER BY ORDER_DATE LIMIT 1) 
    AND 
        (SELECT DATE_ADD(ORDER_DATE, INTERVAL 10 YEAR) FROM ORDERS ORDER BY ORDER_DATE LIMIT 1)
) 
AND C.ORDER_ID = O.ID order by O.ORDER_DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.NAME, O.PRICE
FROM ORDERS O, CUSTOMERS C 
WHERE O.PRICE = 
(   SELECT MAX(PRICE) FROM ORDERS 
    WHERE ORDER_DATE BETWEEN 
    (SELECT  ORDER_DATE FROM ORDERS ORDER BY ORDER_DATE LIMIT 1) 
    AND 
    (SELECT   DATEADD(year, 10, ORDER_DATE) FROM ORDERS ORDER BY ORDER_DATE LIMIT 1)
) 
AND C.ORDER_ID = O.ID 
ORDER BY O.ORDER_DATE
```

Comment: Range is incorrect as i am filtering 10 years data
WHERE ORDER_DATE BETWEEN 
    (SELECT  ORDER_DATE FROM ORDERS ORDER BY ORDER_DATE LIMIT 1) 
    AND 
    (SELECT   ORDER_DATE FROM ORDERS ORDER BY ORDER_DATE LIMIT 1)

Answer (score 0):

mysql doesn't support **Top**. use **LIMIT** like this

```
 SELECT C.NAME, O.PRICE
FROM ORDERS O, CUSTOMERS C 
WHERE O.PRICE = 
(
    SELECT MAX(PRICE) FROM ORDERS 
    WHERE ORDER_DATE BETWEEN 
    (SELECT ORDER_DATE FROM ORDERS ORDER BY ORDER_DATE LIMIT 1) 
    AND 
    (SELECT DATEADD(year, 10, ORDER_DATE) FROM ORDERS ORDER BY ORDER_DATE LIMIT 1)
) 
AND C.ORDER_ID = O.ID ORDER BY O.ORDER_DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL DB:

```
SELECT C.NAME, O.PRICE 
FROM CUSTOMERS C, ORDERS O 
WHERE C.ORDER_ID = O.ID AND
      O.ORDER_DATE <= DATE_ADD((SELECT MIN(ORDER_DATE) FROM ORDERS), interval 10 year)
ORDER BY O.PRICE DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).